# PDF Not Correctly Decoded... I open PDF from API Call OK, but cannot open after saving (VS 2015 - C#.NET Framework 4.8)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, pdf-generation, .net-4.8

I can open the PDF (which opens up in a new browser tab in my MVC .NET Framwork 4.8 C# web app) using the following code , and this used to work, but the company is using a new API and I had to modify it to get it to work and it opens, but when I save it, I cannot open the PDF from the saved copy.

I can save and open from the old API - Here is how I do it.:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(api.URI);
    if (buffer != null)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    }
}
```

Here are the modifications I had to do to get it to open in the new tab with the new API:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    Byte[] buffer = wc.UploadData(URI, "POST", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(QS1)); 
               
    if (buffer != null)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    }
}
```

The PDF opens correctly and looks normal, but when I save it, I cannot re-open it. I get the following error when I try to open the saved PDF:

[image: Error when you try to open the PDF]

When I open the saved PDF in Notepadd++ I see the following:

[image]

Comment: Why is the first line of your notepad++ screenshot showing "<?xml"? That is definitely NOT how a PDF starts, so it's effectively a malformed/corrupt PDF file.

Comment: @Ryan I found a solution and will post it once I meet my deadline. Thanks!